# SFTP Processbuilder

Tags: java, unix, sftp, processbuilder

I have to invoke unix commands from Java and I have to use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). I want to login through SFTP using key authentication and I want to SFTP the file from local directory to remote location.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sftp","-oIdentityFile=privateKey","-b","commands.txt","username@hostname");
```

Content in commands.txt is

```
put localFileDirectory remoteDirectory
exit
```

Is there any way that I can give localFileDirectory and remoteDirectory in processbuilder? Those should be dynamic and I have to give it processbuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

1. Use the `scp` command instead. It does the same ssh-based file transfer, but allows you to specify source and destination on the command line.

   ```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("scp", "-i privateKey", "-r",
       "localFileDirectory", "username@hostname:remoteDirectory");
   ```

   The `-r` is for "recursive", needed if you are transferring a whole folder. It's not needed if you're just transferring a single file.
2. Generate the `commands.txt` file from your Java code.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMedico. I tried first option, It says "exec request failed on channel 0 lost connection".looks like SCP is not installed in my target machine

Comment: Huh. I thought the scp and sftp clients used the same server-side mechanism, but maybe not.

Comment: @AndrewMedico actually no, SFTP is a subsystem of SSH while scp requires the permission to open a shell or execute commands on the SSH server; shell and sftp are two totally different things.

Comment: Any suggestions if I want files **created in last 24 hours** only to be copied from the remote server to local.